# Spring, No Hibernate Session bound to thread

Tags: multithreading, spring, hibernate

I'm getting this error and I don't figure out why it is.

I have defined my transactionManager:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="com.transaction.data.HibernateTransactionManager"> --> my own class
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="txTemplate" abstract="true"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
            <prop key="get*">
                PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED,readOnly
            </prop>
            <prop key="list*">
                PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS,ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED,readOnly
            </prop>             
            <prop key="*">
                PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have defined my beans like this:

```
<bean id="managerImpl" parent="txTemplate"  scope="singleton"> --> I undersstand that it's inside a transaction and it should be work only with this.
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="com.myapp.manager.ManagerImpl">
            <property name=".." --> many DAO's      
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean> 

<bean id="engine" class="com.engine.EngineImpl" scope="prototype">
    <property name="manager" ref="manager"/>
</bean>
```

And my controller for MVC

```
<bean name="/user/main.htm"
    class="com.pragsis.bidoop.aw.ctrl.user.MainController">
    <property name="engine" ref="engine" />
    <property name="formView" value="public.init"/>     
    <property name="successView" value="public.init" />
</bean>
```

On my code, I create a Thread inside of my controler. This thread has a Engine bean, and I get a Session from Hiberante with getCurrentSession from my DAO's. I got the exception when I do this. One thing that I did, it was changing the declaration of my "engine" and do it parent of "txTemplate" and it works, but, I don't understand why it's not working if it's just my manager a child of "txManager". 
I know that Session in Hiberante are not thread-safe and they have been created inside a transaction, but I understand that my "manager" is inside a transaction.

Updated:
The code of my Controller is:

```
@Override
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response, final Object command,
        final BindException errors) throws Exception {
   ...
        ExecuteEEThread execute =
                new ExecuteEEThread(engine, HDFSfileSystem);
        execute.start();

        HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();
        sesion.setAttribute("status", execute.getStates());
    }



return mav;
    }
```

And my thread is:

```
public final class ExecuteEEThread extends Thread {    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean executing = true;
       ....
        try {
            if (executing) {
                states.put("EE", EXECUTING);                    
                engine.process();
                states.put("EE", END);

                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    log.debug("Engine ended.");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ....
        }
....
    }
```

Finally the kind of code that I execute in my manager and where I get the exception is a simple DAO like this.

```
 private void configurationSet() {
        List<TableUser> rtList =
                manager.getTableUserDAO().list(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE); --> excepcion

       ......
    }
@Override
    @PostFilter("filterObject.owner==null or hasRole(filterObject.owner)")
    public List<TableUser> list(final int init, final int maxValue) {
        final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); --> exception
        return crit.list();
    }
```

I was wrong about the HibernateTransactionManager that I'm using. I have using this one.

```
 * @author Juergen Hoeller
 * @since 3.1
 * @see #setSessionFactory
 * @see #setDataSource
 * @see org.hibernate.SessionFactory#getCurrentSession()
 * @see org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils#getConnection
 * @see org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils#releaseConnection
 * @see org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
 * @see org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager
 * @see org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HibernateTransactionManager
```

Comment: Post the code which creates the thread and gets the session. Also why do you use the old and deprecated `TransactionProxyFactoryBean` you should avoid that as much as possible (as this will give you a lot of headaches). Also why do you have your own implemenation for a `HibernateTransactionManager` what is so custom about it? Also `scope="singleton"` is the default and that has nothing to do with transactions.

Comment: What do you mean with: scope="singleton" is the default and that has nothing to do with transactions??

Comment: Yes as it states. Spring beans are singleton by default. And the fact that something is or isn't singleton has nothing to do with the fact that transaction might or might not work. Please add the stacktrace you get.

Answer (score 0):

Start with removing the TransactionProxyFactoryBean as it is cumbersome to use and will lead to errors on one point (injectnig wrong dependency non-proxied instances etc.). You are using Spring 3.1 (or hihger) with Hibernate 4.

I would recommend using `@Transactional` on your `com.myapp.manager.ManagerImpl` class.

```
@Transactional
public class ManagerImpl extends Manager {}
```

Then in your configuration add `<tx:annotation-driven />` instead of the `TransactionProxyFactoryBean` (if you have more you can remove all of them). I would start with a `@Transactional` on the class level and see if you can get it to work, if it works modify the different methods according to your current config.

Your manager is transactional but the first thing you do is bypass all transactions by directly invoking the dao (whichyou even do with an ugly getter on the manager).

```
manager.getTableUserDAO().list(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

The code above bypasses all transaction configuration. You should have a method on your manager which lists the user (or make the `TableUserDao` also transactional (which by now should be nothing more then adding `@Transactional` to it).

You are starting threads in a JEE container which is basically something you shouldn't do. I strongly recommend using springs `TaskExecutor` abstraction for this. You could create a `prototype` scoped bean to represent the task you want to execute and simply pass it to the executor. This gives you a reusable `ThreadPool` and nice integration with the containers thread management, next to that it also allows spring to inject the dependencies into your task (instead of doing that yourself). And frees you from working with `Thread`s yourself.

Comment: Thank you, I have a little question about the manager. I thought that if my manager is transactional but I say nothing about my "TableUserDao", this's going to be transactional as well.. I don't really understand why I'd mark my Dao as transactional as well. Is it not enough with the manager? Imagine that I'm going to insert a record through my DAO and an exception happen, I'd throw that exception and it would work because the manager is transactional, right?.

Comment: Oh, everything should be easier with annotations but we want to keep all the code with the same style and we don't use too many annotations. That's why I haven't marked the classes with @Transactional. Thanks a lot about your advise with  Threads!, I'm going to read about TaskExecutor.

Comment: Then at least use `<tx:advice />` together with `<aop:config />` to mark your transactions. You really don't want to use the `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean` anymore. It was used and needed in the Spring 1.x timeframe and should be considered deprecated as of some time.

Comment: The methods on the manager are indeed transactional however as soon as your `getTableUserDAO` is done the transaction is gone. It will only work if you have a list method on your manager you shouldn't use a manager/service or whatever and then pull out its dependencies...

Comment: Yes, I like more <aop:config>, I have another project that I use it. I have to read the advises and disadvantages about TransactionProxyFactoryBean.I have no idea, I'll look for information about it. What I don't understand why I got the initial error if a manager is inside an transaction when I try to get the currentSession from another class. Is there an simple explication? Well, I did "Engine" child of transition, and it works, although, I don't like it. So, do I have to create the transition before I call "start"?Could it work as well if DAO would be transactional?

Comment: You weren't inside a transaction that was the whole problem. I would say that your code is to complex and can probably be simplified. I would also suggest that you read up on how spring applies AOP (that is used for transactions) and get some understanding of that.